# Trying to check data frequency with Pandas Series of datetime64 objects

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some time series data that can be 1Hz, 10Hz, or 100Hz. the file I load in happens to be 1Hz:

```
In [6]: data = pd.read_csv("ftp.csv")

In [7]: data.Time
Out[7]: 
0             NaN
1     11:30:08 AM
2     11:30:09 AM
3     11:30:10 AM
4     11:30:11 AM
5     11:30:12 AM
6     11:30:13 AM
```

I convert it to datetime with:

```
In [8]: time = pd.to_datetime(data.Time)

In [9]: time
Out[9]: 
0                    NaT
1    2015-03-03 11:30:08
2    2015-03-03 11:30:09
3    2015-03-03 11:30:10
4    2015-03-03 11:30:11
5    2015-03-03 11:30:12
```

From here how can I verify what the sampling frequency is? Do I have to do this manually or can I use a built in pandas method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method after converting to datetime64, if frequency sampling rate is the same then we could call `diff()` to calculate the difference between all rows which should be the same and compare this with a `np.timedelta64` type, so for your sample data this would be:

```
In [277]:

all(df.datetime.diff()[1:] == np.timedelta64(1, 's')) == True
Out[277]:
True

In [278]:

df.datetime.diff()
Out[278]:
0
1        NaT
2   00:00:01
3   00:00:01
4   00:00:01
5   00:00:01
6   00:00:01
Name: datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
In [279]:

df.datetime.diff()[1:] == np.timedelta64(1, 's')
Out[279]:
0
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
Name: datetime, dtype: bool
```

to check if the freq was 10hz or 100hz just change the units to `np.timedelta64` so for 10hz: `np.timedelta64(100, 'ms')` and for 100hz: `np.timedelta64(10, 'ms')`

The `np.timedelta64` units can be found here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic

Comment: You may also want to use `numpy.allclose` with a specified tollerance if the sampling speed is not perfectly 1 second.

Comment: Yes that's true you may get inconsistent sampling with the higher sampling rates

Comment: @bischoffingston I just tried that method and it seems incompatible with the dtype used by pandas you may have to convert the values to a np.datetime64 or other dtype that will make it compatible

Comment: convert the diff series which is a timedelta64 to a datetime64, use the allclose method, convert it back to timedelta64 then check it is how i'm seeing it.

Comment: I'd just thought about that too ;)

Comment: That seems like a bug. I just filed a bug report https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5630  @EdChum can you post the code you used to get that bug there?

Comment: also, you should just be able to do `np.allclose(np.datetime64(timeseries))`. Why would you convert it back? Just use the original `timeseries` object!

Comment: @GarrettLinux not sure what you're suggesting but the following was what I tried which didn't work: `np.allclose(df.datetime.diff()[1:], np.timedelta64(1, 's'))`